# Python: list() function messes up map()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, filter

I was playing a bit with the `map()` and `filter()` functions at python 3.
I tried to take a list and filter it and then on the filter object to do a map function:

```
f = list(range(10))
print(f)
print('-----------')
y = filter(lambda a: a > 5, f)
print(list(y))
print(y)
print(type(y))
print('-----------')
x = map(lambda value: value+1, y)
print(list(y))
print(y)
print(type(y))
print('-----------')
print(list(x))
print(x)
print(type(x))
```

The result is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
-----------
[6, 7, 8, 9]
<filter object at 0x7f46db255ac8>
<class 'filter'>
-----------
[]
<filter object at 0x7f46db255ac8>
<class 'filter'>
-----------
[]
<map object at 0x7f46db3fc128>
<class 'map'>
```

When I comment out the `print(list(y))` it suddenly works well.
Did you encounter this? What am I doing wrong?
I run python 3.6.3 on ubuntu.

Comment: Calling `list()` on `y` consumes the iterator. Iterators can only be used once. When you call the output of `y` a second time in `print()` there are no values left to yield. You can see this simply with: `y = filter(lambda a: a > 5, f); print(list(y)); print(list(y))`

Comment: @roganjosh you should post this as an answer.

Comment: As @roganjosh said, you may need to store `list(filter...)` to a variable and use it wherever you need.

Comment: @Austin Sorry for that I corrected it.

Comment: @sloth I'm trying to find if there is a good dupe, surely there is a canonical?

Comment: You might have been trying to do this rather: `x = map(lambda value: value+1, list(y))`?

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you !!

Answer (score 13):

Iterators and generators can only be consumed once. When you call `list(y)`, it yields all of the values in the sequence and is then exhausted. When you try to see the contents a second time, there is nothing left to yield, so you get an empty list back.

This is more-clearly demonstrated with:

```
f = list(range(10))
print(f)
print('-----------')
y = filter(lambda a: a > 5, f)
print(list(y))
print(list(y))
```

Which gives:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
-----------
[6, 7, 8, 9]
[] # Nothing to yield
```

If you want to keep the values in `y` you will need to assign it to a name:

```
y = list(filter(lambda a: a > 5, f))
```

Comment: Could we also just `y = list(filter(lambda a: a > 5, f)`  then `print(y)` now when we want to use `y` in the future we don't have to use `list` everytime we call `y`

Comment: @vash_the_stampede yes, that is what I am suggesting in the bottom line. The point of calling `list()` twice is that the second one will print an empty list

Comment: @vash_the_stampede I've added some clarification, thanks

Comment: yeah agree was just suggesting to demonstrate `y = list(filter(lambda a: a> 5, f)` so that in answer so OP knows how to properly create a variable holding filtered list

Comment: something like , "the proper way to assign filtered list to variable is... ", he knows now how not to do it but no one has demonstrated how to properly create variable `y`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with roganjosh's response, but let's see if I can add a little extra:

What's a bit confusing about the `filter()`, `map()`, and `reversed()` functions is that they don't return lists (as you might expect), but instead return iterators.  (This is stated in the help text that you can read when you type `help(filter)`, `help(map)`, and `help(reversed)`.)

So now that you know that they return iterators instead of lists, you might be wondering:  Why does that matter?  Well, iterators are meant to be iterated over once (that is, no more than once), like in a for-loop such as `for i in iterator:`.  And something that's important to keep in mind is that *once an iterator is iterated over, it no longer has any more elements left to iterate over*.

To illustrate, consider this code:

```
backwards = reversed( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] )   # creates an iterator; not a list!
myList = list(backwards)   # iterates over the iterator to create a list
print(myList)   # prints "[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]", as you'd expect
myList = list(backwards)   # nothing left to iterate over, so creates an empty list
print(myList)   # prints "[]" (an empty list)
```

So what do you do if you want to get a list from `filter()`, `map()`, and `reversed()`, instead of an iterator?  Well, you can immediately wrap those function calls in `list()` and use that result when you need it, like this:

```
myList = list( reversed( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ) )
# Now use myList whenever you need it, without worrying that it will disappear.
```

Or, you can replace `filter()` and `map()` with list comprehensions, like this:

```
f = list(range(10))
y = [a for a in f if a > 5]  # you can use this instead of filter()
x = [a + 1 for a in f]  # you can use this instead of map()
```

And as for replacing `reversed()`?  Try this:

```
z = f[::-1]  # you can use this instead of reversed()
```

You might be wondering:  If I can use replacements for `filter()`, `map()`, and `reversed()`, why would I ever use them?

The answer is because sometimes you'll need to filter, map, or reverse an enormous list, and that creating another (huge) list just to loop/iterate over would be very wasteful and time-consuming.  So returning an iterator prevents another huge chunk of memory being used up -- just know that when the iterator is spent (that is, iterated over), its information is gone.